# Criar aplicação web que execute casos de teste JUnit em arquivos java que serão submetidos por uma página?

Tags: java, testes, junit

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação parecida com um juíz online, mas tudo o que quero é que após submetido um arquivo java através de uma página html ou jsp, a aplicação execute um certo caso de teste do JUnit naquele arquivo java e mostre os resultados em uma nova página. Estou com problemas para raciocinar a melhor forma de fazer isso, pois eu sei que conseguimos rodar testes do JUnit em arquivos java que já estão dentro do projeto, mas não sei como fazer em um arquivo java que está para ser submetida no banco de dados da aplicação. Alguém sabe de algo que possa me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desconsiderando a segurança envolvida, isso pode ser até fácil. Entretanto, não tente executar dentro da sua aplicação.

1. Crie um projeto vazio (sem classes) em algum diretório do servidor que tenha as dependências necessárias, neste caso, o JUnit. Sugiro usar Maven.
2. Garante que você tem o JDK e o Maven disponíveis em linha de comando
3. Crie um modelo de classe vazia e forneça para os usuários, se achar necessário.
4. Cada vez que alguém submeter uma classe:

   1. Crie um diretório temporário único (`File.createTempFile`)
   2. Execute outro processo no diretório temporário com o comando `mvn test`. O maven deve compilar a classe e executar a classe de teste automaticamente.
   3. Os resultados do testes estão dentro da pasta `target/surefire-reports`.

Se quiser um pouco de segurança, provavelmente uma imagem Docker e o [Maven Docker Plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin) para executar os testes de forma isolada e segura. Entretanto, isso vai exigir um pouco mais de pesquisa e configuração do sistema para funcionar bem.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção. Eu achei sua resposta muito útil e tentarei desenvolver dessa forma. Comentarei sobre os resultados assim que os tiver.